# Untouchable items

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am running a command, but I want to use it for only items that **aren't** a few. Is there a way to make an entity untouchable by commands?

Comment: What do you mean by untouchable?

Comment: make their NBT tags un-modifiable by commands @ModDL

Comment: It's impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I figured it out. You should use a **tag**

```
scoreboard players tag @e[put whatever you want here] add example
```

That would add a **tag** to any item you want. Then, you do your buisness, while adding *"tag=!example"* in selector. For instance:

```
tp @e[tag=!example] ~ ~20 ~
```

or

```
entitydata @e[tag=!example] {CustomName:"I am touched by the command"}
```

In this case, *"example"* is the name of a **tag**. You don't need to do anything else to make it work. You just add any tag you want to any entity with the first command, and it's all set to be added to selectors.

And, to answer the initial question, no, it's impossible to make entity completely ntouchable by any commands. The only 2 solutions are:

> - Killing the entity
> - Using additional selector modifications, like **tag**s, radius, number, e.t.c

Comment: Im kinda confused. Could you please expand on what "example" is

Comment: This doesn't fulfill the desired action. Untouchable appears to mean the _NBT_ data can't be modified, and this can also be touched by a normal command.

Comment: Affiliation to what?